# averaging every five minutes data as one datapoint in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe

I have a Dataframe in Pandas like this

```
1. 2013-10-09 09:00:05
2. 2013-10-09 09:01:00
3. 2013-10-09 09:02:00
4.  ............
5.   ............
6.   ............
7. 2013-10-10 09:15:05
8. 2013-10-10 09:16:00 
9. 2013-10-10 09:17:00
```

I would like reduce the size of the Dataframe by averaging every 5 mins data and forming 1 datapoint for it ..like this

```
1. 2013-10-09 09:05:00
2. 2013-10-09 09:10:00
3. 2013-10-09 09:15:00
```

Can someone help me with this ??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you may want to look at [pandas.resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df['Data'].resample('5Min', how='mean')
```

or, as `how = 'mean'` is default parameter:

```
df['Data'].resample('5Min')
```

For example:

```
>>> rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=10, freq='Min')
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':np.random.randint(0, 500, len(rng))}, index=rng)
>>> df
                     Data
2012-01-01 00:00:00   488
2012-01-01 00:01:00   172
2012-01-01 00:02:00   276
2012-01-01 00:03:00     5
2012-01-01 00:04:00   233
2012-01-01 00:05:00   266
2012-01-01 00:06:00   103
2012-01-01 00:07:00    40
2012-01-01 00:08:00   274
2012-01-01 00:09:00   494
>>>
>>> df['Data'].resample('5Min')
2012-01-01 00:00:00    234.8
2012-01-01 00:05:00    235.4
```

You can find more examples [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#up-and-downsampling).