# Calculate every 5 minute returns using 1 minute data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 1 minute price data as Python pandas dataframe like this:

```
          Date                Time      Open      High       Low     Close  
390 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:31:00  1146.210  1147.020  1146.210  1147.020   
391 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:32:00  1147.120  1147.339  1147.120  1147.219   
392 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:33:00  1147.100  1147.630  1147.100  1147.630   
393 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:34:00  1147.700  1147.700  1147.439  1147.469   
394 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:35:00  1147.560  1147.730  1147.560  1147.680   
395 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:36:00  1147.700  1147.700  1147.640  1147.640   
396 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:37:00  1147.810  1147.810  1147.430  1147.430   
397 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:38:00  1147.310  1147.310  1147.110  1147.110   
398 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:39:00  1147.050  1147.050  1146.870  1146.870   
399 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:40:00  1146.860  1147.120  1146.860  1147.110   
400 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:41:00  1147.020  1147.170  1147.000  1147.170   
401 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:42:00  1147.219  1147.250  1147.150  1147.210   
402 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:43:00  1147.210  1147.210  1146.969  1146.969   
403 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:44:00  1146.850  1146.850  1146.510  1146.510   
404 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:45:00  1146.390  1146.510  1146.280  1146.510   
405 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:46:00  1146.110  1146.110  1144.819  1144.819   
406 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:47:00  1144.439  1144.439  1144.060  1144.060   
407 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:48:00  1144.200  1144.350  1144.120  1144.120   
408 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:49:00  1143.890  1143.930  1143.890  1143.930   
409 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:50:00  1143.910  1144.010  1143.770  1144.010   
410 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:51:00  1144.210  1144.360  1144.210  1144.360   
411 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:52:00  1144.490  1144.850  1144.490  1144.850   
412 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:53:00  1145.110  1145.219  1144.910  1144.910   
413 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:54:00  1144.930  1144.969  1144.930  1144.960   
414 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:55:00  1144.920  1144.920  1144.770  1144.770   
415 2004-04-13 1900-01-01 09:56:00  1144.830  1144.939  1144.800  1144.800
```

I want to calculate the 5-minute returns, that is, log(09:35:00 Close/**09:31:00 Open**), log(09:40:00 Close/09:35:00 Close),...,log(15:55:00 Close/15:50:00 Close), log(16:00:00 Close/15:55:00 Close).

And then I want to take the sum of quartic returns. How can I do this? Thanks.

If I use datafame.shift(5) and then calculate the returns what I obtain is the rolling 5 minute returns, which is not exactly what I want.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Comment: This would also work http://stackoverflow.com/a/32207339/6664393

Comment: Possible duplicate of [averaging every five minutes data as one datapoint in pandas dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048200/averaging-every-five-minutes-data-as-one-datapoint-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

User `pd.TimeGrouper('5T')`

```
df = df.set_index(df.Date + (df.Time - pd.to_datetime(df.Time.dt.date)))

cols = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']
agg = np.log(df[cols]).groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('5T')).agg(['first', 'last'])
agg.stack(0).T.diff().dropna().squeeze().unstack()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But what's calculated here is: log(09:34:00 Close/09:31:00 Close), log(09:39:00 Close/09:35:00 Close),..., log(16:00:00 Close/15:56:00 Close). However, what I want is log(09:35:00 Close/09:31:00 Open), log(09:40:00 Close/09:35:00 Close),...,log(15:55:00 Close/15:50:00 Close), log(16:00:00 Close/15:55:00 Close). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @CofeinnieBonda, if you going to use pandas, you need to take a tutorial on pandas. What you are asking in easily done with pandas, but you need to explore how to do it.  Otherwise,  you will most of the answers on SO un-achievable.