# Average data by each hour in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data like below:

[image]

Data Columns:

```
DateTime,Data1,Data2,Data3,Month,Date,Year,Hour,Minutes
1/1/2017 0:00,1.1,2.2,3.3,1,1,2017,0,00
1/1/2017 0:00,1.1,2.2,3.3,1,1,2017,0,15
1/1/2017 0:00,1.1,2.2,3.3,1,1,2017,0,30
1/1/2017 0:00,1.1,2.2,3.3,1,1,2017,1,45
```

I need to average columns 'WS', 'VWS' .... 'SR' data by each hour. The DateTime column is reported every 15 minutes.

Comment: send some code you have done ...

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048200/averaging-every-five-minutes-data-as-one-datapoint-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 8):

I have an answer to my own question. Posting it here so that others can benefit:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("MetData.csv")

df['NewDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df.index = df['NewDateTime']
df_p = df.resample('H').mean()

df_p['Month'] = df['NewDateTime'].dt.month
df_p['Year'] = df['NewDateTime'].dt.year
df_p['Date'] = df['NewDateTime'].dt.day
df_p['Hour'] = df['NewDateTime'].dt.hour

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('MetData_Orig1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df_p.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```